# Is possible to use lambda expression in linq to sql?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, lambda

I wonder if you can do something like this:

```
    public List<T> FindOrder<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T : class
    {
        DbSet<Preventivos> preventivos = this.Preventivos;

        return (from p in preventivos
                where predicate
                select new...
```

Comment: of course `preventivos.Where(predicate).Select(e => new ...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with an `Expression`.  If your parameter were just a `Func<T, bool>` then you could treat `predicate` as a delegate:

```
     return (from p in preventivos
            where predicate(p)
            select new ...
```

Which will probably fail when the provider tries to convert to SQL since it needs have the metadata of an `Expression` to generate the equivalent SQL.

You could try to `Compile` the expression first to convert it to a `Func<T, bool>`:

```
    return (from p in preventivos
            where predicate.Compile()(p)
            select new ...
```

Which will *compile* but may still fail at runtime when the query provider tries to convert it to SQL.

So unless you're *really* hung up on using query syntax, method syntax would be much cleaner:

```
return preventivos.Where(predicate)
                  .Select(p => new ...);
```

Answer (score 4):

Not like that, no - but you *can* write:

```
return preventivos.Where(predicate).Select(...);
```

... although your code example seems to be unclear as to whether this is really generic or whether it only deals with `Preventivos`.

The point is that the query expression you've provided would add an extra "wrapper" layer:

```
return preventivos.Where(p => predicate)
                  .Select(p => new { ... });
```

... whereas you want to pass the predicate expression tree *directly* to the `Where` call.

Comment: but, this way not?

`from p in preventivos
                where predicate
                select new`

Comment: @EleazarCelis He already answered that question.  It's right in the first half sentence.

Answer (score 0):

To complement Jon's answer, here's a selection from some actual working code (in use @ www.NJtheater.com) allowing you to look a venue by ID# or name

```
    public void Display(int id)
    {
        Display(ven => ven.VenueID == id);
    }

    public void Display(string name)
    {
        Display(ven => ven.Shortname == name);
    }

    public void Display(Expression<Func<Venue, bool>> whereClause)
    {
        Venue venue = db.Venues.Where(whereClause).FirstOrDefault();

           /// etc
```